# Excel - Create a rolling average (most recent 10 occurrences) from an AVERAGEIFS formula

Tags: excel, dynamic

I am trying to create a rolling average based on the most recent 10 instances that meet three conditions from my dynamic data set.

I have currently managed to get the formula working based on one conditional statement, however now I need to modify it to include two more conditions.

What I have so far:
=AVERAGE(IF(B1:B65=B71,IF(ROW(B1:B65)>=LARGE(IF(B1:B65=B71,ROW(B1:B65)),10),L1:L65)))

The conditions I want to add - in the format of (criteria range, criteria) are as follows:
(Q1:Q65,"1") and (D1:D65,F71).

Im not sure if its easy to just add these into the existing formula ive worked on, or if I need to start again with another method? Bit out of my depth here so advice appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a version of Excel that supports Dynamic Arrays? (eg Excel 365)

Comment: Yes, using excel 365

Comment: Have a look at `Filter`

Comment: Why not use averageifs() and if the data entries are in entry or time order, just use the last cell position and pick the 9 previous.

Comment: Yes they are in entry order... so how do i go about picking the 9 previous entries? As in, how do I modify my AVERAGEIFS formula to do so?